# Right join a table twice to a second table with each alias inner joined to to a third table's two aliases

Tags: join, inner-join, alias, firebird

Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. Here is what I'm trying to do and my problem.

I have 3 tables.
assets (a computer, network device, etc)
ports (a port on the computer, network device, etc)
port_connections (has a port_id_a and port_id_b field and links each port and therefor each asset together)

It's really just a way to track vlans and network devices/computers in office buildings.

I'm using the newest version of firebird using dialect 3. I'm assuming this isn't a firebird issue and just an problem with my sql.

I know this must be possible because I can do it with just right joins (ports to port_connections) and do the other joins in the WHERE clause. The issue with this is the right joins are lost when I join the assets table to the ports table.

EDIT: this is the newest query I'm working with because the old ones are useless at this point. My issue with this newest query is it seems to be pulling items that are linked though the port_connections table twice. So I will get the proper port_connections record and then I get a duplicate record with just the single port without a port_connection. I need to get rid of this later record somehow but still keep the other port records that don't have a port_connection record.

```
SELECT
port_connections.connection_id,

asset_a.name AS asset_a_name,
port_a.port AS port_a_name,
port_a.asset_id as asset_a,

asset_b.name AS asset_b_name,
port_b.port AS port_b_name,
port_b.asset_id as asset_b,

port_connections.description

FROM
port_connections

right JOIN ports AS port_a
ON port_connections.port_id_a = port_a.port_id

right JOIN ports AS port_b
ON port_connections.port_id_b = port_b.port_id

left JOIN assets as asset_a
ON asset_a.asset_id = port_a.asset_id

left JOIN assets as asset_b
ON asset_b.asset_id = port_b.asset_id



WHERE
(port_a.asset_id = 2 OR port_b.asset_id = 2)
ORDER BY port_a_name, port_b_name
```

Tables:
assets:

```
ASSET_ID
SYS_ID
LOCATION_ID
NAME
DESCRIPTION
"TYPE"
AQUIRED
DISPOSED
MFG_NAME
TAG_NO
```

port_connections

```
"CONNECTION_ID"
PORT_ID_A
PORT_ID_B
DESCRIPTION
```

ports

```
PORT_ID
ASSET_ID
PORT
TITLE
DESCRIPTION
"TYPE"
SPEED
```

EDIT: The fix was to move the connection_id into the ports table and this query then does what I wanted.

```
SELECT
port_connections.connection_id,

asset_a.name AS asset_a_name,
port_a.port AS port_a_name,
port_a.asset_id as asset_a,

asset_b.name AS asset_b_name,
port_b.port AS port_b_name,
port_b.asset_id as asset_b,

port_connections.description

FROM
port_connections



right JOIN ports AS port_b
ON port_connections.connection_id = port_b.connection_id

right JOIN ports AS port_a
ON port_connections.connection_id = port_a.connection_id

left JOIN assets as asset_a
ON asset_a.asset_id = port_a.asset_id

left JOIN assets as asset_b
ON asset_b.asset_id = port_b.asset_id

WHERE

port_a.asset_id = 2
AND
(port_b.asset_id != 2 or port_b.asset_id is null)

ORDER BY port_a_name
```

Comment: Would it be possible to modify your question to include the schema of these three tables? I'm trying to make sense of the joins and it's tough without a table layout to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your query so it compiles, and included it below. The error you're seeing about the unexpected table name is on the INNER JOIN line - you gave the left table name again, and you don't need to, since SQL uses the join criteria (the ON clause) to determine what the left table is.

Does this return all the rows you expect, or are you expecting to see some results that you're not?

```
SELECT
port_connections.connection_id,

asset_a.name AS asset_a_name,
port_a.port AS port_a_name,
port_a.asset_id as asset_a,

asset_b.name AS asset_b_name,
port_b.port AS port_b_name,
port_b.asset_id as asset_b,

port_connections.description

FROM
port_connections
RIGHT JOIN ports AS port_a
ON port_connections.port_id_a = port_a.port_id

RIGHT JOIN ports AS port_b
ON port_connections.port_id_b = port_b.port_id

INNER JOIN assets as asset_a
ON asset_a.asset_id = port_a.asset_id

INNER JOIN assets as asset_b
ON asset_b.asset_id = port_b.asset_id

WHERE
(asset_a.asset_id = 2 OR asset_b.asset_id = 2)

ORDER BY port_a_name, port_b_name
```

**EDIT:**
I think I see what's going on here. Because you're RIGHT JOIN-ing from Connections to "port a", it will return those rows even if the INNER JOIN later (port a to asset a) doesn't have a match, because of the way the RIGHT JOIN behaves. To exclude the rows that aren't plugged in, I think you'll just need to modify your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
(asset_a.asset_id = 2 OR asset_b.asset_id = 2)
  AND asset_a.asset_id IS NOT NULL
```

This will filter out rows for which asset_a is NULL, ie where there's no match there because nothing is plugged in.

Comment: This worked (minus the two commas). I changed the Inner joins to Left joins and now it seems close however it gets extra records.

For example I have one computer/asset with one port and one port_connection to a port on a router. This new query will give me the computer as asset_a and the router as asset_b, this is correct. The next record has asset_a null and the computer again under asset_b.

It seems it's somehow cross linking port_id_a and port_id_b in the join so it's showing up twice even though the computers port record is only linked once on port_connections.port_id_a.

Comment: You would get extra records if you're not joining on the entire key in one of your left/right joins - if, for example, your key is made up for portname and computername, but you only join on computername, you'd have two records for port, and it wouldn't know which one to join to, so it would return both. Is that what's occuring? To tell, you might need to expand your SELECT list to include some additional fields from your computer table to see which fields are causing the duplicates.

Comment: My keys are port_id on the ports table, and asset_id on the assets table. For a single computer with one port it will return asset_a/port_a as the computer, asset_b/port_b as the router it's plugged into. The next record is a duplicate of the computer information under asset_b/port_b and a null asset_a/port_a. Where it shows up (under a or b) has to do with the order of my joins but no matter what I try I can't get rid of these duplicates. If i could somehow set a distinct so every port is only listed once between port_a and port_b alias tables.

Comment: I have tried the "AND asset_a.asset_id IS NOT NULL", however it doesn't return ports that are not yet linked to port_connections.

Comment: I think the NULL row you're seeing just identifies a port that's not connected to anything - it seems like you want to return these disconnected ports based on your description. Maybe you could use an "ISNULL(asset_a.asset_id, 'Disconnected)" or something like that to more clearly signify that these represent ports not associated with a connection.

Comment: Although not what I did you definitely pointed me in the right direction. I simply moved my port_connection id into the ports table, that way each port has a connection. I can now use this port_connection_id field to check if they are connected or not making this far more simple to figure out.
I think I was confusing things by trying to make set two connection points.
Thanks for sticking with me!